# Trying to read the text from an element on a website

Tags: python, selenium

Hello This is my first post but I am trying to make a bot right now and for the bot to work i need to look at the a value that change. `<div id="pronoun-input">Shakira y Selena</div>` I would like to get the Shakira y Selena part. I am doing this in python. Any help would be appreciated.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBLEt.png)

Comment: The ID is pronoun-input not #pronoun-input  that's a CSS_SELECTOR.

Comment: Furthermore you should be waiting for visibility of the element with webdriver waits.